# Ajax requests are not cached by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code for making ajax request. I am trying to determine request are cached or not by using chrome tool. In request tab i see all datas always pulled from server and there is no any "cache" in status text column.

How can i detect that request are cached or not. And I think result are not cached so what is wrong on my code ?

```
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            dataType:'html',
            cache:true,
            success: function (data) {
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`cache` is by default set to true for HTML. If you sent to false jQuery adds a parameter in a query as in '_=201105XXXX".

If the query was not part of the URL, it means that the request page was cached.